# Is this a bug in g++ c++14 support?

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

It seems that with `auto` parameters g++ just uses first `auto` it encounters. Is this a bug?

```
auto f(std::vector<auto> a)
{
    a.push_back('0');
    return std::string("");
}
```

http://ideone.com/T69ytm

Comment: Yes, it is a gcc bug. It should not've accepted `std::vector<auto>`.

Comment: This is not standard C++14. Concepts support is a GCC extension.

Comment: `auto` parameters are allowed in lambdas, not in regular functions. `std::vector<auto>` is not an allowed form in lambdas either.

Comment: ideone.com suppresses a lot of error messages , I suggest using gcc.godbolt.org instead.  Using `-std=c++14 -pedantic`, gcc 4.9.2 gives me a diagnostic message for the line `auto f(std::vector<auto> a)` so I would not say this is a bug.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64969; https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69448

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @SergeyA, this is a GCC bug. `std::vector<auto>` should not have been accepted.